# python-docx: tables missing from document.tables

Tags: python-docx

When trying to access a table in the word document below, tables before the table of contents are missing from document.tables
https://www.fedramp.gov/assets/resources/templates/FedRAMP-SSP-High-Baseline-Template.docx

Here is an example of me importing the doc and checking the first table in the tables list and the corresponding table in section 1 of the document (after the table of contents):
https://puu.sh/DBm0O/86ee455e03.png

Here is the table I'm trying to access 
https://puu.sh/DBm2f/4d447baa2e.png

I assume that there's something related to the table being in the beginning of the document before the table of contents, but I can't find any other posts about something similar.

Any recommendations on how I could access this table (without moving it) using python-docx? Am I stuck using the underlying lxml element directly? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The underlying XML in a .docx document can be inspected using `opc-diag`, something of a companion project to `python-docx`.

```
opc browse FedRamp.docx document.xml
```

Inspection reveals that the front-matter in that document is enclosed in a `<w:sdt>` element. "sdt" stands for Structured Document Tag. I don't know what those are exactly, but they are possibly related to content controls. In any case, their presence effectively hides whatever they contain from `python-docx`. A similar behavior arises with unaccepted revision marks. `python-docx` is just not sophisticated enough to deal with the complexities introduced by these "advanced" containers present in certain .docx documents.

If you can remove those containers somehow, restoring their contents to the "top-level", everything should work. If you're using this file as a template, then editing them using Word or even editing the XML by hand will perhaps be quickest. If they are inputs that continuously arrive to you this way, perhaps pre-processing the XML of the `document.xml` part is a viable approach.

Comment: Thank you for this, I really appreciate it. Saving the template as a .doc then a .docx again does convert the "Content Controls" (which I believe are the sdt elements) back to normal tables. If I load the new .docx back into python-docx it shows all the tables as expected. I'll have to play around with what the best solution to this is from a practical standpoint to get rid of content controls automatically.

Regardless, thank you for your help and all the work you do on python-docx, it has been immensely helpful.

Comment: Youbetcha Bill :)

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution made using BeautifulSoup and not python-docx. What I have done here is traversed through OOXML of word(.docx) document.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import zipfile

wordoc = input('Enter your file name here or name with path: ')
text1 = 'templaterevisionhistory'
document = zipfile.ZipFile(wordoc)
xml_content = document.read('word/document.xml')
document.close()
soup = BeautifulSoup(xml_content, 'xml')

more_content = soup.find_all('p')
for tag in more_content:
    if ''.join(tag.text.split()).lower() == text1:
        table = tag.find_next_sibling('w:tbl')
        table_contents = []
        for wtc in table.findChildren('w:tc'):
            cell_text = ''
            for wr in wtc.findChildren('w:r'):
                # We want to exclude striked-out text
                if not wr.findChildren('w:strike'):
                    cell_text += wr.text
            table_contents.append(cell_text)
        print(table_contents)
```

Comment: Hi sorry thanks for your answer but I am specifically looking for someone familiar with python-docx to give some feedback on this issue. My main project is a wrapper around python-docx specific to these templates. I removed the python tag from the post since I imagine that might have been confusing.

Comment: As correctly said by @scanny, the content is enclosed in a <w:sdt> element. Try moving the front matter inside <w:body> element in document.xml file which is present in the word folder after unzipping the word file.
Steps to unzip the .docx file: [here](https://www.groovypost.com/howto/howto/explore-the-contents-of-a-docx-file-in-windows-7/)